# What about short facts?

Tags: discussion

I just opened a question in which i asked for the longest (in characters) movie title, which has attracted some negative comments.

I would like to know why some facts like that are not good for a Q&A site.

Some more question i could think of:

`Longest movie (in time)`

`Most people killed in a movie`

Is this wolfram alpha approach bad?

Isn't it part of cinematic history just like:

`First movie with sound (not instruments)`

`Highest grossing movie of all time`

etc?

Comment: In my opinion your question is completely on-topic but the down vote is due the fact that your question is found not interesting by some users.

Comment: personally i find it irritating that someone downvotes questions that he finds not interesting. i thought downvote is a feature to show that the question: a) does not fit into the site, b) is poorly written, c) leads to discussions and opinions.

Comment: @Wandang No, a) and c) is what close-votes are for.

Answer (score 3):

I think the question is valid and on-topic.  Others think that it is not constructive (a reason for closing a question on stack-exchange).

Personally I think that it is perhaps not that interesting, and downvoted the question as a result.

However I do not own the site - it is owned by the community here.  Questions like this **if phrased well** are answerable, and it is not for me to dictate whether they are interesting or not - I can vote it down to make my personal opinion known, but I do not see the necessity to wield moderator powers and close it out of hand.

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, I really don't care for these sort of questions.  They're not interesting, and they honestly don't add to the appreciation of whatever film ends up being the answer.  To me, these are all trivia questions.  I also don't care for the "what was the first film to" questions, but those at least add a little appreciation to the film because it broke new ground in something.

Comment: I just don't think it is for me to judge what someone else finds interesting or not.  I don't find the question interesting at all, so I downvote it.  I am reluctant to close a question just because I don't care for it.